# Using Apple Script to find a product code in excel spreadsheet in column A and past an value from clipboard in row C?

Tags: excel, applescript

Much appreciate your help.

I have a spreadsheet with products listed in rows and details of the products in the columns.

I am trying to get excel to find a product code within column A and then paste the corresponding value that is already in the clipboard into Column C. I am using the following script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    set searchRange to range ("A1:A5")
    set foundRange to find searchRange what "AM100" with match case
    set fRow to first row index of foundRange
    set myData to value of range ("B" & fRow as text)
    set theClip to the clipboard as text

end tell
```

I can't seem to make the paste happen in column C on the same row where the product code has been found.

Please help...

Many thanks
Darryl

Comment: i don't use Excel but "set theClip to the clipboard as text" does nothing in Excel, that just assigns the clipboard to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Give this solution a try.

It finds and replaces every instance of your search term with the clipboard text.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    set search_range to range "A:A" -- look in column A
    set search_term to "AM100"
    set found_range to ""
    set counter to 0
    try
        set found_range to find search_range what search_term look at whole with match case
    on error
        log ("No matches found")
    end try

    if (found_range is not "") then
        set first_cell_address to (get address of the cells of found_range)
        log ("first_cell_address = " & first_cell_address)
        repeat while true
            set cur_row to the first row index of found_range
            set mod_cell to cell cur_row of column 3 -- the same row in C column
            set value of mod_cell to (the clipboard as text)
            set counter to counter + 1

            -- Now look for next result
            set found_range to find next search_range after found_range
            set cell_address to (get address of the cells of found_range)

            if (cell_address = first_cell_address) then -- have looped around so we are finished!
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat

    end if

    log ("found " & counter & " items")

end tell
```

Applescript-ing Excel can be quite confusing but at least it's still supported (*cough* apple)

Comment: Hey @user3015153, did this work for you? Be great to mark the question as answered if so.

Comment: It did yes.Many thanks and apologies for the late reply